# Creating new SQL based on comparision between 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't quite get my head around the issue I'm running into.

Temp Table A (generated from JSON file):

```
TABLE Director (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255)
);
```

Table B:

```
TABLE Movie (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255),
    DirectorName varchar(255),
    Genre varchar(255)
);
```

Now I want to create a third table with director that made a horror movie, which contains the same Ids and Names as in the Director table. Like so:

Table C:

```
CREATE TABLE HorrorDirector (
    Id int,
    Name varchar(255)
);
```

So I've to filter the directors (table A) based on the genre (table B).

How could this be done?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: But why? If you are leaning to design databases, then you've already taken a wrong turn. And generally you don't "make another table" to store duplicate information that can easily be queried using simple SQL. If you are simply learning TSQL, you should start with a good tutorial using a well-designed schema. MS has pretty good sample databases that are also a good starting point.

Comment: It's not quite duplicate data, as table A is a temp table from a JSON file. Maybe I should've included that in the question,,

Answer (score 1):

Probably it should not be a table, it should be a view, something similar to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW HorrorDirector() AS
SELECT D.id, D.name
  FROM Director D
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Movie M WHERE M.directorName = d.Name)
```

If you really want a table, you still can do something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE HorrorMovies
AS SELECT D.id, D.name
  FROM Director D
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Movie M WHERE M.directorName = d.Name)
```

In addition, it is strange in your data model that movies have names of directors instead of id, probably a foreign_key would be a better choice.

Comment: I think this is almost what I'm looking for, but it's missing 1 piece: I want to create table HorrorDirector, so it should check if the genre is actually 'Horror'

Comment: yes inside the exists. I forgot that :D